# New Mac. Certain hotkeys not working in certain programs

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-monterey

I just bought a new Mac (M1 Macbook Pro). I spent today working on it and noticed that some keyboard shortcuts don't seem to work properly.

In VSCode, anything shortcut with `cmd+[` doesn't work. For example, `shift+cmd+[` should move to the tab to the immediate left of the current tab. This shortcut works in chrome and terminal, but not in VSCode. According to VSCode keybinding debugger, it's not receiving `cmd+[`, though it receives everything else.

Meanwhile "cmd+`" is supposed to cycle through windows of the same program. This works in terminal, but not in chrome or safari. It just makes a ping noise.

I'm not sure how to debug this. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an English keyboard? US or UK? Is your input language also set to English? Some of this moves around depending on language. You can double-check which key command is expected for 'cycle through windows' by the OS in the Finder Window menu [it often doesn't show as its own command in many apps, though it should still work] Cycle windows itself only works within one Space, though it shouldn't beep if it can't find any windows to cycle, it should just 'do nothing visible'. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/193937/85275

Comment: US keyboard using US keyboard settings. I've tried debugging with a keylistener and the key presses are being sent to the system properly. I can cycle through finder windows no problem. Same with terminal. but chrome and safari don't.

Comment: hmmm… odd. Does Safari respond to Cmd + [number] to direct-select tabs by position? Check you have the default key combo setup correctly in System Prefs > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Keyboard

Comment: Oh snap! I checked the keyboard shortcuts earlier but looking more closely now, it was set to use forward tick instead of backtick. No idea how that could have happened. Thank you! Still struggling with the VSCode one though.

Comment: Glad you found it. I'm not very good with "terminals/coding environments" in the broadest sense, except to know that some of them do odd things with key commands. I hope someone else picks up on this part & can help you further. Wish you luck :))